# Как в OpenGL сделать полноэкранный режим?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

Я учу OpenGL вместе с библиотекой glfw3 Как в OpenGL сделать полноэкранный режим?  Или это делается на glfw3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делается это через GLFW.
Для этого вызывается метод `glfwSetWindowMonitor` первым аргументом передается окно, вторым монитор, в котором он должен быть на весь экран.